# Object Box and Graph Queries

Tags: objectbox, flutter-objectbox, objectbox-android

With ObjectBox supporting documents / objects and relations, does it support graph queries? It seems other non-graph databases like MongoDB also have some graph database like support, but hadn't quite figured out if ObjectBox does.

Sorry wish there was a Discord or more of a forum type place to ask this, as it is not quite a Stack Overflow type question.